# How do Pixels behave on different devices

Tags: css, media-queries, mobile-devices

Please excuse me if this question appear to be stupid but I am really a beginner on this matter.

Let'suppose I need to create a web page wich have the following layout

```
+----------------------------------------+
|             Img1 and overlay text      |
|                                        |
+--------------------+-------------------+
| img2 and           |   Img3 and        |
|    Overlay text    |   Overlay text    |
+--------------------+-------------------+
```

And this page would need to be visible on mobiles, tablet, desktop, either vertically or horizontally.

It is sufficient to say things like: "Image1 text overlay should be 60px in height" to have it working everywhere at the same manner?
Or should I define different font size based on common media breakpoint?
Moreover, does media query based on `device-width` are sufficient to create a design for those device covered by the media query or do I need to take in account also the CSS pixel ratio when designing a site?

Thanks!

Comment: I would go for `em` instead of `px`, unless you really need an exact size.

Comment: Ok. Can you please elaborate more? If I use pixels, what types of problems do I have to expect?

Comment: Read this blog post to start with: [The 2014 Guide to Responsive Web Design](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/modern-field-guide-responsive-web-design). It also contains links to other useful information. It's a bit too much to talk about in a simple answer, I'm afraid.

Comment: yes, you need to explain a bit more , typically you would use pixels , then just make the height maybe go down a little bit for different screen types.  If yuo were do to a percentage for height then it would be too extreme big and small as the screen size changes .  You could do like 20px for xlg screen, 17 lg, 15sm 10xs, etc

Comment: Thankyou everybody. The linked reference was really interesting. I am just investigating to understand the guidelines, so I dont have further more details just now.